# bootstrap nested panels in grid of equal heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two rows of nested panels inside of a primary panel. The 1st row has 3 panels of unequal heights. How do I make the 3 panels to be the same height of the highest panel (panel #3 in the jsfiddle link)?

Here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/niner911/MgcDU/8905/

I would like panel #1 and panel #2 the same height of panel #3, or whichever the tallest panel would be.

Thanks for the help.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">outer</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">1</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <div class="list-group-item">111</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">2</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <div class="list-group-item">222</div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">222</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">3</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <div class="list-group-item">333</div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">333</div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">333</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span>lower</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                      xyz
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `map()` to process each item and get the size of the tallest panel. Than apply this height to each panel.

JS

```
var heightTallest = Math.max.apply(null, $(".panel-info").map(function ()
{
return $(this).outerHeight();
}).get());
$('.panel-info').css({ height: heightTallest + 'px' });
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8915/

using jquery apply height to children of .row

```
$('.row').each(function(){
 var RowHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
 $(this).children().css({ height: RowHeight + 'px' });  
});
```

and set .panel height to what size you desire, eg. 100%

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with the browser compatibility limitations, you could try this CSS flexbox-based experimental code: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11851