# Getting all list-group-items to be the same size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="list-group">
  <p class="list-group-item-text">(one line)</p>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">(one line)</p>
  <p class="list-group-item-text">(two lines)</p>
</div>
```

I want all `.list-group-item-text` to have the same height, which is that of the largest one.

So from the code above, the first two items would expand to the size of the third one.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21892511/1661745) but it's not responsive.

Edit: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/grzt/m0dyer0r/) is the solution, courtesy of [karan3112](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25197593/1661745)

Comment: Can you fiddle your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [element with the max height from a set of elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060992/element-with-the-max-height-from-a-set-of-elements)

Comment: @TusharGupta Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/grzt/wz3hvnrg/

Comment: might be this link work for you. http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to loop through each item and use a temp variable to get the maximum value.

Wrap the item's inner content in a div, in this case `.list-group-item-wrapper`

**EDIT** : used outerHeight()

JS

```
    var temp = 0;
    $('.list-group .list-group-item-wrapper').each(function (index) {
      if($(this).outerHeight() > temp)
      {
        temp = $(this).outerHeight();
      }          
     });
    $('.list-group .list-group-item-wrapper').css('min-height',temp);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/wz3hvnrg/2/)

Comment: Although the smaller list items did expand, they were still smaller than the biggest list item.

Comment: Give a fiddle link of your code so I can understand better.

Comment: This is because of the padding given to the `.list-group-item-text`. Try wrapping the `a` tag in a div and use the div in the above logic to calculate the max height.

Comment: This is a good solution.  However, when the window is extremely shrinked, the height differs again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58935/discussion-between-karan3112-and-onepiece).